# Image Upload Function Not Working - Multipart Form Data

Tags: ios, swift

Swift 5.7

I am trying to send 3 images along with some other data to my server via a multi part form data request.
When I try to send the request with the following code, my server is not hit at all, **unless I remove the last two images from the request**. What am I doing wrong? I need to be able to send all 3 images in the same request if possible.
I've shortened the code down to the part that you need to see. I've been stuck on this. Any direction will help.

Service.swift

```swift
        let networker = Networker()
        let serverUrl = URL(string: "https://myurl.com")
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: serverUrl!)
        
        let boundary = UUID().uuidString
        
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let requestData = networker.buildMultipartImageRequest(boundary: boundary, item: items)
        
        URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: requestData) {(data, response, error) in
...
}.resume()
```

Networker.swift

```swift
    func buildMultipartImageRequest(boundary: String, item: ItemForBackend, itemId:UInt = 0) -> Data {
        var data = Data()
        
        // add the image data to the raw http request data
        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images\"; filename=\"\(item.filename1)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append(item.image1)
        
//    If I uncomment these next two portions, the request won't send at all!
//        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
//        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images\"; filename=\"\(item.filename2)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
//        data.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
//        data.append(item.image2)
//        
//        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
//        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images\"; filename=\"\(item.filename3)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
//        data.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
//        data.append(item.image3)
        
        // add the rest of the item's info to the multipart form data
        let paramObj:[String: Any] = item.getParams()
        
        for(key, value) in paramObj {
            data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            data.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        }
        
        if itemId != 0 {
            data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"itemId\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            data.append("\(itemId)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        }
        
        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        
        return data
    }
```

Comment: after each ```data.append(item.imageX)``` try adding ```data.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)```

Comment: Try adding the images after the other data. Give each of the 3 images a unique "name" on the "Content-Disposition" line. Also, can you confirm that `item.image2` and `item.image3` are `Data` instances representing JPG data of an image?

Comment: @udi thanks for the suggestion. I tried that one and no luck though.

Comment: @HangarRash I tried those suggestions and still am having the issue. I also can confirm that those data instances are representing JPG data.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping this here for future reference in case anyone else runs into this problem. The problem turned out to be that the request was too large for my server and I was getting a 413 error back that I missed...so if anyone else in the future comes across an issue such as this make sure that you aren't sending too much data.
Nothing was wrong with my formatting.